# How to create custom skin like WinAmp

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

I guess this question has been ask before, but I have not found sufficient answer to even start poking around. Most answer refers to catching WM_PAINT method directly and do custom rendering, or use a onwer draw object. However, I did not see a centralized place that has the info. to start researching. Hence, the question.

My goal is to create a very simple GUI program with custom look into it. I prefer the way winamp does their custom look that is customizable through "skins". However, I am not interested in using some cross-platform library like GTK+, QT or wxWidget.

I have some experience in system programming, but not much for GUI. I spent most of my time developing console applications, and I just started doing some QT development. If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be very appreciated.

PS: I am interested in both windows and linux environment.

Comment: You're not interested in using a cross platform library, yet you want to support both Windows and Linux? You mean you're planning to write your application twice?

Comment: Use OpenGl. It's a cross platform hardware accelerated graphics library, similar to DirectX.

Comment: Fernandes, I am just interested in the low-level implementation to actually create custom GUI, not how to use the libraries. I do not intend to support both OS, just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody,

Sorry for the late reply. I had a chance to have a quick talk with the original developer for winamp, and this is the quick answers I have:

1. Using skins: Artists create skins, developer will render the skins
2. To the OS (Windows), winamp is just one pretty box, nothing else. There is a container windows, and that's about it
3. All controls (button, label, list, etc) are implemented by winamp team themselves. All messages and stuffs are passed as relative position to the container window. WinAmp and the GUI engine has to decide if a button is clicked or if the label next to it is the target, etc.
4. Rendering artists skins created in XML

I do not have the details on if they use any libraries to do all that, but I am suspecting they do hook a window call directly, and do custom rendering themselves.

Answer (score 0):

GUI skin usually using plug-in mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is exactly what you are looking for:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/428800:weekend-project-creating-qt-interfaces-with-gimp?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed

Comment: Puel, as asked, I am not intended to use cross-platform library, including QT

Answer (score -1):

I also interested in creating custom look of window and widgets.

Speaking about widgets it's not hard, just need to create subclass (if you are using C++) or some widget and implement some methods like draw, handle etc. But this solution is good only if you use some high-level library like GTK, QT, etc. If you want to implement all controls by your own, you may get any graphics library, which can create window and do any graphics inside. For example, SDL2 + Cairo. SDL2 for creating window, Cairo for vector rendering controls/widgets. Both of this libraries are for win and linux. Another option is take opengl/vulkan + some lib for rendering window. It could be SDL2, SFML, GLFW.

If you really interested how it works on low level, then search Windows API for Windows and XLib or XCB for Linux/X.Org.

Speaking about window, I still investigate it. However I have one thought: you may create an empty window and then draw whatever you want. Then you need to add handlers for resizing window on the borders. But I am not sure if it's good solution, and if it won't freezes.